# Socket.io Transport unknown

Tags: cordova, socket.io

I'm implementing socket.io in cordova (phonegap 3). I've used the socket.io plugin but I always
got this error:

```
 {"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}
```

Comment: Are you setting `io.set('transports', ...)` in your server? Also, make sure that the client and the server are using the same SocketIO library version.

Comment: I've updated socket.io version and everything is fine already.